# BASH - can't find what the $? special variable means

Tags: linux, bash

Anyone knows what `$?` means in BASH?

I have to write a script that restarts a process if it crashes or is killed.  So I found this to start from :

```
RESTART="/etc/init.d/apache2 restart"
if [ $? -ne 0 ] # if apache not running
then
   # restart apache
   $RESTART
fi
```

I have done a search, but $? eludes me.

I am not sure if the above script is the best way to do this, I am assuming that $RESTART will hang until the process is killed or dies? If not, I would assume there would be some kind of sleep() call in there so this thing doesn;t spin at 1000 miles per hour.

Comment: This and other special variables can be found under "Special Parameters" in the bash man page. The string "$?" isn't actually used anywhere, which makes searching difficult.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Anyone know what $? means in bash

It's the exit status of the most recently executed command.

```
[cnicutar@fresh ~]$ ls /nothing
ls: cannot access /nothing: No such file or directory
[cnicutar@fresh ~]$ echo $?
2

[cnicutar@fresh ~]$ ls -ld .
drwx------ 15 cnicutar users 4096 Aug 16 15:29 .
[cnicutar@fresh ~]$ echo $?
0
```

Look it up at [tldp](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html).

Answer (score 0):

Q: cant find what bash $? means

A: It's the "return status" of the program.

```
/* In this example, "$?" from "./hello" will be "0": Status == OK */
#include <stdio.h>

int main (argc, char*argv[])
{
  printf ("Hello world!\n");
  return 0;
}
```

Here is a list of "special shell variables":

- http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/scrpt/scrpt2.2.2.html